# react js show hide other common components properties from other components

Tags: reactjs

I am having issues with show and hide loader.
Having loader on app common component and now i want to hide and show loader from other controller.

Loader code is as below

```
class App extends Component {

render() {

return (
        <div class={"loader"+ (this.props.isloading ? '' : 'hide')}>
         </div>
 )}
 }
 App.defaultProps = {
   isloading: false
 };
```

In other Components if i want to make props true to show loader and make it false to hide loader.

Problem is how to show loader from other component? 
how to set "isloading" properties to true or false in other components

Comment: What is your problem exactly with other components ? Components are all working the same way, dealing with `props` and `state` to render their content.

Comment: why don't you make one `Loader` component? which can be used everywhere by importing that component.

Comment: Problem is how to show loader from other component?
how to set "isloading" properties to true or false in other components

Comment: @AviatorX
can you suggest me example?

Comment: Can you show us some of your code that is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your app into **reusable components**, following code is just snippet so you can adjust code according to your need

`Loader Component`

```
export class Loader extends Component {

    render() {

          return (
             <div class={"loader"+ (this.props.isloading ? '' : 'hide')}>
              </div>
          )
    }
 }
```

`App component`

```
import Loader //just a snippet give proper path in your code
class App extends Component {

    constructor() {
        this.state = { isLoading: true }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
         this.setState({isLoading: false})
     }

    render() {

        return (
            <Loader isloading = {this.state.isLoading} />
         )
     }
 }
```